# jquery select option to construct queryString

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a `query parameter` for when doing a search, I managed to build it with `input` field however there's a `select` dropdown menu to select other values.

```
<input type="text" id="dd">
<select name="" class="sel">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Prepare">Prepare</option>
  <option value="Ready">Ready</option>
  <option value="Cancel">Cancel</option>
</select>

<button onclick="buildQuery()">Build query</button>
```

jQuery code for query building the query param

```
function buildQuery(){
  var result = "?";
  var getVal = $('input#dd').val();
  console.log('Input > ', getVal);
  var getSelectVal = $('select#sel').val();
  if (getVal != null && (getVal != "")) {
    let inputValues = getVal
    .split("\n")
    .filter(function (str) { return str !== "" })
    .join("&test=");
    // then add it to the overall query string for all searches
    result = result + 'test' + "=" + inputValues + "&";

    console.log('Results > ', result);
  }
```

Not sure how can I get the value from the `select` and construct it similar way to my input console.log output `Results >  ?test=f&`

So if you fill in the `input` and `select` an option it the queryParam should say something like `?test=inputVal&test=selectVal` or individual `?test=inputVal` or `?test=selectVal`

What I can do is copy the whole `if()` statement and replace the `getVal` with `getSelectVal` but it seems inefficient and duplicating the code.

**Actual code --**

```
newSearchParams.properties.forEach(function (inputSearch) {
        // first reparse the input values to individual key value pairs
        // Checks which field is not null and with empty string (space)
        var getVal = $('textarea.input_' + inputSearch.name).val();
        var getSelectVal = $('select.select_' + inputSearch.name).val();
        if (getVal != null && (getVal != "")) {
            let inputValues = getVal
                .split("\n")
                .filter(function (str) { return str !== "" })
                .join("&" + inputSearch.name + "=");
            // then add it to the overall query string for all searches
            result = result + inputSearch.name + "=" + inputValues + "&";
        }
    }, this);
    // remove trailing '&'
    result = result.slice(0, result.length - 1);
    return result;
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wdecqe9/4/)

Comment: test=inputVal&test=selectVal is valid i mean same prop 2 values ?

Comment: yes I've tried and the select is valid and with proper values

Comment: Is this you trying to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/3wdecqe9/1/ just remember to remove the last & symbol

Comment: not quite, that will only get the `select` value that will leave the input.

Answer (score 2):

In case Shibi's answer passing test as array is not fine for some reasons,

The following serializes your two form elements' values into id=value&id2=value2 using `jQuery.param()`:

```js
function buildQuery(){
  var $elements = $('#dd, #sel'), //or your selector
      result = {};
  
    $elements.each(function(){
      if(this.value !== '') 
        result[this.id] = this.value; //uses id attribute as variable name
    });
  
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = '?' + $.param(result); //see jQuery.param() docs
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="dd">
<select name="" id="sel">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Prepare">Prepare</option>
  <option value="Ready">Ready</option>
  <option value="Cancel">Cancel</option>
</select>

<button onclick="buildQuery()">Build query</button>

<p id="log">(This element is here just for logging the result)</p>
```

Comment: Interesting, ill give it a try. Yeah my first approach was to use jQuery but when I pass the queryString name `jQuery.param({input.name:val})` something like that didn't accept it because of `input.name`

Comment: Yeah `$.param` look like its build for this reason. I would use it too. :)

Comment: See my edit above with my actual `input` and `select` code

Comment: @MrNew  If you want to use a variable as an object key, first name that object ( `var obj = {}`), then use brackets: `obj[yourVar] = 'some value'`. This is already in the answer.

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev mind editing the answer using variable as an object key?

Comment: @MrNew It's already in the answer: `result = {};  result[this.id] = this.value;`

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev can't seems to make it work like ` var $elements = $('select.select_' + inputSearch.name, 'textarea.input_' + inputSearch.name)` though if I only put 1 parameter works okay.

Comment: In the question, your select has no classes. Here in comment you are selecting it by a .select_XXX class name. Did your HTML change somehow?

Comment: This selector is wrong: `$('select.select_' + inputSearch.name, 'textarea.input_' + inputSearch.name)`.

Comment: Ah yeah it was my mistake in my selector, it supposed to be `class` but should work whether using an `id` or `class`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134790/discussion-between-matvey-andreyev-and-mrnew).

Answer (score 1):

I will do it like this and then you can add more inputs as you wish..

```
function buildQuery(){
    var result = '?test=';
    var getVal = $('input#dd').val();
    var getSelectVal = $('select#sel').val();
    var resultArray = [getVal, getSelectVal]; // all values array
    resultArray = resultArray.filter(v=>v!=''); // filter empty results
    if(resultArray.length > 1) {
        result += resultArray.join("&test=");
    } else {
        result += resultArray[0];
    }

    result = encodeURI(result);
    console.log(result);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3wdecqe9/6/

Comment: what's the weird encoded vals? `?test%5B%5D=s&test=1` is it possible to remove those and have a clean `test=value` instead? Looks like its the `test[]` can you explain that?

Comment: yes its because I did the test[] as an array so you could read all his values in the server side. its like when you doing `form.serialize()`

Comment: can it be just `?test=value` instead?

Comment: I update the code so its be without the array now its `?test=value`

Comment: Yeah get that remove `[]` will clean it, but what's with the `encodURI(result)`

Comment: You can remove it too if you like.. its encode the url so you could send it in ajax..